# How to clean up a chunk of memory and put new variables there?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I intended to clean up a chunk of memory then put a struct variable in it and assign new values in that newly cleaned memory, but I couldn't initiate the struct variable from the address which the pointer variable points to `(ptr=00D51590)`. As indicated in the program [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBAv2.png) with red arrows, I cannot get rid of the remnants of old memory variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct DataSet{
    char data1;
    int data2;
    char data3;
    short data4;
};

int main(){

uint8_t *ptr;

    struct DataSet data;

    ptr=calloc(16,sizeof(uint8_t));

data.data1=0x11;
data.data2=0xAABBCCDD;
data.data3=0x55;
data.data4=0xAABB;

printf("Value of ptr=%p\n\n",ptr);
ptr=(uint8_t*)&data;
uint8_t totalSize=sizeof(struct DataSet);

printf("Memory address                  Content\n");
printf("=======================================\n");

for(uint8_t i=0;i<totalSize;i++){
    printf("%p=                         %X\n",ptr,*ptr);
    ptr++;
}
printf("\n\nTotal memory consumed by struct variable=%d\n",sizeof(struct DataSet));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're leaking memory with `ptr = (uint8_t*) &data;` because ptr points to the space allocated by `ptr = calloc(16, sizeof(uint8_t));`

Comment: Also, please format your code better. You can use an online tool like this https://techiedelight.com/tools/clike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This instruction already allocates memory (on the stack):

```
struct DataSet data;
```

and this allocates memory *elsewhere*, on the heap:

```
ptr=calloc(16,sizeof(uint8_t));
```

So, what you are trying to do is never going to work.

You can do:

```
struct DataSet *data; // This is now a pointer

data = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Dataset));
ptr  = data; // The two pointers point to the same memory

data->data1 = 0x11;
```

Or you can just assign ptr to &data with your old code, now ptr points to the stack. "Manually" operating on memory is really not recommended.

You may also want to use `valgrind` to inspect potential troubles in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You want pointer punning (not good but if you access only sizeof(char) long data and pointer allocated dynamically, it is OK). Probably you want:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

struct DataSet{
    char data1;
    int data2;
    char data3;
    short data4;
};

int main(void){

    uint8_t *ptr;

    struct DataSet *data;

    ptr=calloc(16,sizeof(*ptr));

    data = (void *)ptr;
    data -> data1=0x11;
    data -> data2=0xAABBCCDD;
    data -> data3=0x55;
    data -> data4=0xAABB;

    printf("Value of ptr=%p %p\n\n",(void *)ptr, (void *)data);

    printf("Memory address                  Content\n");
    printf("=======================================\n");

    for(uint8_t i=0;i<16;i++){
        printf("%p=                         %"PRIx8"\n",(void *)ptr + i,ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nTotal memory consumed by struct variable=%d\n",sizeof(*data));
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/r73K81

But generally, union punning is much safer

```
struct _DataSet{
    char data1;
    int data2;
    char data3;
    short data4;
};

union DataSet
{
    struct _DataSet ds;
    uint8_t raw[sizeof(struct _DataSet)];
};

int main(void){

    union DataSet *data;

    data = calloc(sizeof(*data),1);

    data -> ds.data1=0x11;
    data -> ds.data2=0xAABBCCDD;
    data -> ds.data3=0x55;
    data -> ds.data4=0xAABB;

    printf("Value data=%p %p\n\n", (void *)data);

    printf("Memory address                  Content\n");
    printf("=======================================\n");

    for(uint8_t i=0;i<16;i++){
        printf("%p=                         %"PRIx8"\n",(void *)&data -> raw[i], data -> raw[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nTotal memory consumed by struct variable=%d\n",sizeof(*data));
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dM55Ej